# When add border for li,an error appears

Tags: html, css

```js
 var ul=document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
 ul.addEventListener('mouseover',function(e){
  if(e.target.tagName.toUpperCase()=="LI"){
   e.target.style.border='1px solid red';
  }
 })
```

```css
 ul,li{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
 }
 ul{
  margin:200px;
  width:560px;
  height:500px;
  border:1px solid red;
 }
 li{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:green;
  float:left;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0px 10px 10px 0px ;
 
 }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator"
    content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39" />
    <title></title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
    </ul>

  </body>
</html>
```

I write the code, when the mouse over the li from the right to left in the second row,then mouse over the first row,the second li drops down,if add border for all li label,the error will disappear,but i want to know why,who can teach me?Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming, by 'error appears' you mean to say that the layout changes?

Comment: You can either use the CSS3 box-sizing property -  `box-sizing:border-box` on the li css. or add an initial border to the `li`. You could just remove the `javascript` entirely, and use `li:hover { border:1px solid red }` - unless you need the new border colour to remain.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback,when i add "box-sizing:border-box",it works well, i will study the css property,thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
ul.addEventListener('mouseover',function(e){
    if (e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() === "LI") {
        e.target.style.border = '1px solid red';
    }
})
```

```css
ul, li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

ul {
    margin: 200px;
    width: 560px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

li {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator"
    content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39" />
    <title></title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
    </ul>

  </body>
</html>
```